# How to get rid of horizontal scroll in a PrimeNg table15?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, primeng, p-table

Is there any atribute of the PrimeNg 15 *p-table* component that will make make table fit to the screen and not generate a horizontal scrool no matter how many columns there are to be displayed?

In PrimeNg 12 I used to use the *[scrollable]* atribute but it seems not to work this way in the newer version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles on this problem, try adding this css to your component, solved it for me:

```
.p-datatable table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```